# Il bisbetico Vincenzo - Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I do not speak Italian and need your help verifying that such caption would be grammatically correct. Would that translate into "The scoundrel Vincenzo"?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Sorry, but I think that, in the way it is now, this question doesn't fit this site format: questions asking simply if a given text is correct are generally considered off-topic. However, you can edit your post to make it on-topic and I would like to invite you to do it: explain the specific doubts you have about grammar of your phrase. As for its meaning, I would suggest you to try to look for "bisbetico" on a dictionary. Please edit your question to explain what you have found and the doubts you have after doing this.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @Charo. I believe, I got my reply. I will consider your comment for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a caption would be grammatically correct. However its meaning is different from the one you assume. A better translation would be

> The cantankerous Vincenzo

To give you an idea of the connotation of the word *bisbetico*, the feminine form *bisbetica* is how the English word *shrew* in the title of Shakespeare famous comedy [*The Taming of the Shrew*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taming_of_the_Shrew).